# Where to store often used class in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: development, visual-studio, visual-web-part, unique

I have a helper class which is often used in number of webparts. The file contains useful methods. Everytime when I create a new webpart in Visual Studio,  I need to import this file into the project.

Is there other methods to keep the file as global and just reference it from webparts?

Comment: Are you talking about Visual Studio Project in C#?

Comment: @Gwny, yes I am

Answer (score 3):

you can create a separate Project eg. "Common" where you include those classes. You can reference that assembly than from your other Projects. Of course, you have to ensure that this wsp is installed along your other wsps (which use that dll)